# IIS FTP server command MFMT - What versions (if any) support it?

Tags: iis, ftp, ftps

What FTP Service versions of Microsoft Internet Information Services, if any, support the proposed (and now expired?) FTP server command extension [**MFMT**](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-somers-ftp-mfxx-04)?

NOTES

The proposed MFMT ("Modify Fact: Modification Time") FTP command extension modifies a file or folder's last modified date and time information. This complements existing FTP command MDTM ("Modification Time"), [which](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-somers-ftp-mfxx-04#section-1) "which was only [intended](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3659#section-3) to read the modification time and not to set it as some implementations do."

Answer (score 2):

After researching this issue, it appears no versions support FTP server command extension MFMT, as of the date of this answer.

Comment: Not sure how you dig it out, but for others' reference, by connecting to an IIS FTP server, there is a simple way to check supported commands, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lexli/2009/08/12/commands-supported-by-ftpwebrequest-and-iis-ftp/

Comment: Thanks! To summarize the 2009 article: IIS FTP 6 and 7.5 seem to support Microsoft command line FTP program command "remotehelp". From my experience, the IIS FTP server also supports FTP commands "HELP" (RFC 959) and "FEAT" (RFC 2389), which that IIS FTP server instance supports MDTM, or not.